# Selenium freezes after waiting for element (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

we're using the Python bindings of Selenium and django-selenium (SeleniumTestCase) for doing Selenium tests. On our tested page there are HTML elements that are created after some seconds delay. So we want to wait for them and then continue the test. The waiting itself works, but every command after the wait call fails:

```
class SomeTestCase(SeleniumTestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        ... (some testing code that works)
        self.driver.wait_element_present('span.available')  # this works
        self.driver.wait_element_present('span.connected')  # this works, too
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body')  # this fails
```

I debugged through the selenium code and found out that the "find_element_by_css_selector" internally posts an HTTP request to the selenium server (as on every "check if xxx is there" command):

```
http://127.0.0.1:42735/hub/session/<session-id>/element
```

But this request returns with status code 500 and this response text:

```
{
    "status": 13,
    "value": {
        "message": "JSON.parse: unexpected non-digit",
        "stackTrace": [
            {
                "methodName": "Dispatcher.executeAs/<",
                "fileName": "file:///tmp/tmpnUT34U/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js",
                "lineNumber": 7354
            },
            {
                "methodName": "Resource.prototype.handle",
                "fileName": "file:///tmp/tmpnUT34U/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js",
                "lineNumber": 7516
            },
            {
                "methodName": "Dispatcher.prototype.dispatch",
                "fileName": "file:///tmp/tmpnUT34U/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js",
                "lineNumber": 7463
            },
            {
                "methodName": "WebDriverServer/<.handle",
                "fileName": "file:///tmp/tmpnUT34U/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js",
                "lineNumber": 10152
            },
            {
                "fileName": "file:///tmp/tmpnUT34U/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js",
                "lineNumber": 1935
            },
            {
                "methodName": "ServerHandler.prototype.handleResponse",
                "fileName": "file:///tmp/tmpnUT34U/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js",
                "lineNumber": 2261
            },
            {
                "methodName": "Connection.prototype.process",
                "fileName": "file:///tmp/tmpnUT34U/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js",
                "lineNumber": 1168
            },
            {
                "methodName": "RequestReader.prototype._handleResponse",
                "fileName": "file:///tmp/tmpnUT34U/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js",
                "lineNumber": 1616
            },
            {
                "methodName": "RequestReader.prototype._processBody",
                "fileName": "file:///tmp/tmpnUT34U/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js",
                "lineNumber": 1464
            },
            {
                "methodName": "RequestReader.prototype.onInputStreamReady",
                "fileName": "file:///tmp/tmpnUT34U/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js",
                "lineNumber": 1333
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As result the whole test run blocks and is aborted after the default timeout.
According to https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol the status 13 means "UnknownError" which does not make things more clear ;-)

Has anyone discovered this, too? Is there any way to solve this? I do not really know what the exact cause could be, our page structure is clean html code. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Does the method `find_element_by_css_selector` fail for only the parameter *'body'*, or does it fail for other values you pass in too? Does it seem to make a difference which element(s) the locator should be finding?

Comment: It does not matter which element we try to find, it fails for all.

Comment: @dArignac how did you verify ' "find_element_by_css_selector" internally posts an HTTP request to the selenium server'? I'm running into the same issue while using selenium.

Comment: I debugged through the code to the place where the selenium python code posts to its own selenium server and I checked what was returned.  As I already removed the debug output I cannot tell you where I actually found it, sorry.

Comment: Did you try using `find_element_by_tag_name` or `find_element_by_xpath`.

Comment: try to make your test explicit sleep with `time.sleep(time)` and investigate if it is a problem of wait or whatewer

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but--

**wait_element_present** is not a Selenium binding. It's from a custom class from another library called MyDriver https://django-selenium.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#mydriver-class

Selenium explicit waits are more than a simple function: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits

**find_element_by_css_selector** is a Selenium binding for webdriver, and MyDriver does not have a method by this name.

To use custom classes to run Selenium webdriver, you'll need to use the methods it provides (or write your own). In this case, MyDriver has a method called **find** that accepts a CSS selector as an argument and returns the element, which accomplishes what you wanted to do with **find_element_by_css_selector**.
https://github.com/dragoon/django-selenium/blob/master/django_selenium/testcases.py